# Error with getting the Minimum Spanning Tree from a Graph?

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, tree

I am trying to get the Minimum Spanning Tree of an undirected weighted graph, which should return the weight of the minimum spanning tree, or -1 if no minimum spanning tree can be found using a package called CITS2200, below is the link to the CITS2200.jar:

[CITS2200.jar](http://teaching.csse.uwa.edu.au/units/CITS2200/Resources/CITS2200Doc/)

I was wondering if anybody could see why my getMinSpanningTree method in the following code is not passing the test, any help would be appreciated. Cheers, Ben. c",)

```
import CITS2200.*;
public class PathImp implements Path {  

 public int getMinSpanningTree(Graph g) {
    int parent[] = new int[g.getNumberOfVertices()];
    int key[] = new int [g.getNumberOfVertices()];
    Boolean mstSet[] = new Boolean[g.getNumberOfVertices()];
    for (int i = 0; i < g.getNumberOfVertices(); i++)
    {
        key[i] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        mstSet[i] = false;
    }
    key[0] = 0;     
    parent[0] = -1;
    int sum = -1;
    for (int count = 0; count < g.getNumberOfVertices()-1; count++)
    {
        int u = minKey(key, mstSet);
        mstSet[u] = true;
        for (int v = 0; v < g.getNumberOfVertices(); v++){
            if (g.getWeight(u,v)!=0 && mstSet[v] == false &&
                g.getWeight(u,v) <  key[v])
            {
                parent[v]  = u;
                key[v] = g.getWeight(u,v);
                sum += g.getWeight(u,v);
            }
         }
    }
    return sum;
}
public int minKey(int key[], Boolean mstSet[])
{
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE, min_index=-1;
    for (int v = 0; v < key.length; v++)
        if (mstSet[v] == false && key[v] < min)
        {
            min = key[v];
            min_index = v;
        }
    return min_index;
}
 public int minDistance(int dist[], Boolean sptSet[])
    {
        int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE, min_index=-1;
        for (int v = 0; v < dist.length; v++)
            if (sptSet[v] == false && dist[v] <= min)
            {
                min = dist[v];
                min_index = v;
            }
        return min_index;
    }
 public int[] getShortestPaths(Graph g, int src)
{
    int dist[] = new int[g.getNumberOfVertices()]; 
    int graph[][] = g.getEdgeMatrix();                         
    Boolean sptSet[] = new Boolean[g.getNumberOfVertices()];
    for (int i = 0; i < g.getNumberOfVertices(); i++)
    {
        dist[i] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        sptSet[i] = false;
    }
    dist[src] = 0;
    for (int count = 0; count < g.getNumberOfVertices()-1; count++)
    {
        int u = minDistance(dist, sptSet);
        sptSet[u] = true;
        for (int v = 0; v < g.getNumberOfVertices(); v++)
            if (!sptSet[v] && graph[u][v]!=0 &&
                    dist[u] != Integer.MAX_VALUE &&
                    dist[u]+graph[u][v] < dist[v])
                dist[v] = dist[u] + graph[u][v];
    }
    return dist;
}
}
```

The getShortestPath(G, v) method works fine, however, below is the error message I am getting when I test my code against the test class:

```
 Checking files:
 PathImp.java
 Files exist and are readable.

 Compiling Files:
 PathImp
 Compilation complete.

 Loading Files:
 PathImp
 Loading complete.

 Implements CITS2200.Path

Constructing instance...
Constructed PathImp

 Analysing PathImp...
MST:
1
MST incorrect for 500 vertices at 0.03 density.
2
MST incorrect for 1000 vertices at 0.02 density.
3
MST incorrect for 1500 vertices at 0.01 density.
SSSP:
1
Shortest paths correct for 500 vertices at 0.03 density.
2
Shortest paths correct for 1000 vertices at 0.02 density.
3
Shortest paths correct for 1500 vertices at 0.01 density.


!Analysis halted: Your code has produced an incorrect output. 

Your submission was not successful on this occasion.
Please try again when you've addressed this problem.
Execution stack trace (if any) follows.

java.lang.Exception: Your code has produced an incorrect output. 
    at Lab8.main(Lab8.java:86)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is with this line:

```
sum += g.getWeight(u,v);
```

You are adding the weight to your total cost whenever you **consider** adding an edge to the spanning tree.  This will over-estimate the true cost of the spanning tree.

Instead, you should only add the weight when you are **certain** the edge is being added to the spanning tree (i.e. immediately after `int u = minKey(key, mstSet);`)

e.g. something like:

```
int u = minKey(key, mstSet);
if (parent[u] != -1)
    sum += g.getWeight(parent[u],u);
```

Comment: Thanks for the input Peter, I cut the line you said and put it straight after int u = minKey(key, mstSet); Although, I am still not getting the solution correct? I understand what you are saying, maybe I need another approach to the question....Cheers, Ben. c",)

Comment: I've added some example code.  If still not working, I recommend you test it out with some very small cases (e.g. 3 nodes) and confirm that the results agree with expectations.  If not, step through with a debugger to try and trace where it is failing.

Comment: Thanks Peter, I have voted you up, but it won't come into effect until I reach a status of 15...Thanks, Ben. c",)

Answer (score 1):

1. In line : `for (int count = 0; count < g.getNumberOfVertices()-1; count++)` - remove the minus 1: `for (int count = 0; count < g.getNumberOfVertices(); count++)`
2. As Peter mentioned, your problem is in the summing. You don't need to sum during the mst finding process. You need to sum the weights of the found MST in the end:

Remove `sum += g.getWeight(u,v);` from the for loop.

Add after the for loop:

```
int sum = 0;
        for (int v = 0; v < mstSet.length; v++)
        {
            if (mstSet[v] && parent[v] >= 0)
            {
                System.out.println("In MST: (" + (parent[v]+1) + ", " + (v+1) + ")");
                sum += g.getWeight(parent[v], v);
            }
        }

        return sum;
```

Comment: Thanks aviad, I have voted you up, but it won't come into effect until I reach a status of 15...your solution worked perfectly. Cheers, Ben. c",)

Comment: You're welcome. Good luck